# Wanted clarification

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to understand some code which is already written..

I am not able to understand

```
my $l = $0; $l =~ s-/[^/]+/[^/]+$-/lib/perl-;
```

what is assigned to $0 ?
what is - (Hyphen) operator in the expression ?
whay $- is used in the expression?

Please explain the ablove 3Qs.

```
BEGIN {
# figure out our general library path
my $p;
my $l = $0; $l =~ s-/[^/]+/[^/]+$-/lib/perl-; 
push @INC,$l;
# add some platform components, based on files
push @INC,"$l/sunos"  if ( grep /solaris/,@INC );
push @INC,"$l/csw"    if ( grep /csw/,@INC );
push @INC,"$l/i386"   if ( grep /i386/,@INC );
push @INC,"$l/x86_64" if ( grep /x86_64/,@INC );
}
```

Comment: Well, there's more than regex to explain here. Still looks off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can find various Perl special variables in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar). `$0` is explained there.

As mentioned in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop), the substitution operator `s/REGEX/REPLACEMENT/` can be written with different delimiters, e.g. dashes. It's handy when the regex or replacement contain slashes, as is the case here. Using paired delimiters might be more readable:

```
s{/[^/]+/[^/]+$}{/lib/perl}
```

or, using `/x`:

```
s{ / [^/]+ / [^/]+ $ }{/lib/perl}x
```

Comment: Thanks .. that’s answers my questions..

Comment: @SamitKumarPatra: Then accept this as an answer, so it can be closed as solved.